# SSIS error when executing package with removed connections

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm using SSIS on SQL Server 2005 and have run across an error.  As part of the cleanup process I removed a couple of connections from the connection manager section, that we didn't end up using.  But now when I attempt to execute the package I get an error stating that "The connection {some guid} is not found.  This error is thrown by the Connections connection collection when the specific connection element is not found."

I've checked and rechecked, and the connections I've removed are not being used in the package, so it appears this is an unnecessary error.  Is there someplace I can check and clean out this error message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this thread out: [Connection Not Found Issue Resolved](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/2af470ac-d76d-4162-849f-a5e0411aa053)

Answer (score 1):

This was a very strange situation that even I had faced, given that I had updated names of the connection managers and updated the same even in the configuration file.

*Still the package would fail because it was still using the old connection manager.*

It turns out that the package was configured to use SQL Server Logging. Also the package configuration referred the old connection name. [Even though the name inside the configuration  referred the new connection name]. I guess the issue was that it did not correctly update the configuration.

**I resolved this issue by re configuring the connection manager and the default logging.**